# Expected 'styleUrls' to be an array of strings without webpack

Tags: angular, sass

I have this component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal-step',
    templateUrl: './modal-step.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modal-step.component.scss', LoadAssets.getDefaultStyles()]
})
```

I use `LoadAssets` to push an new `scss` inside `stylesUrls`

```
export class LoadAssets {
    constructor() {
    }

    public static getDefaultStyles(): string {
        let _env = window.sessionStorage.getItem('environment');
        return `./assets/styles/images-${_env}.scss`;
    }
}
```

When i try build application, show this error:

[image]

My application doesn't use `webpack` and I've tried several ways, but it doesn't recognize when I put more than one file in styleUrls

Answer (score 0):

There some points that seams not clear to you.

Youre application use webpack, that's because under the hood angular compiler ( now it's Ivy ) use webpack to compile. Precisly at compile time angular will preprocess your css/scss to make possible some of is magic encapsulation stuff:

- [https://angular.io/guide/component-styles](http://%20https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)
- https://angular.io/api/core/Component#encapsulation

The error you get is pretty clear. It expect an array of string : you pass an array of string and a function. It's not possible to use a function because that preprocessing stuff is done - well - at preprocessing time.

Using differents style depending on environnement is a question already asked in stackoverflow and depending of your requirements. There some hints :

- [How to load different global css styles for different environments with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439172/how-to-load-different-global-css-styles-for-different-environments-with-angular)
- [angular-cli: CSS dependent on environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761076/angular-cli-css-dependent-on-environment)
- [Angular Material 2. Switch theme from light to dark on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481704/angular-material-2-switch-theme-from-light-to-dark-on-click)